# How the link in email content work with cakephp3

Tags: email, hyperlink, cakephp-3.0

I want that the user activate his account in clicking the link in the email ,my problem that the link didn't work

**my userscontroller**

```
if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $email = new Email();
                $email->transport('mailjet')
                    ->to('xxxxxxx@gmail.com')
                    ->template('add')
                    ->emailFormat('html')
                    ->viewVars(['nom' =>$user['first_name'],
                        'url'=>['controller'=>'users','action'=>'active',$user],
                         'user'=>$user])
                    ->subject('fffff')
                    ->send();
```

the function active($user) code

```
 public function active($user){

    $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, [
      'state' => 1]);
        $this->redirect('../xxxxxHome/Acceuil');

}
```

**template/Email/html/add.ctp**

```
<?php 
use Cake\Routing\Router; 
use Cake\Routing;
?>
    <strong>Bonjour <?php echo $nom ?></strong>
    <p >Pour activer ce compte suivez le lien </p>
    <?php echo $this->Html->link('Activer mon compte',Router::url($url, true), ['escape' => false]);?></p>`
```

the problem when i call the structure of the url

Comment: Error

An error occurred with your link redirect. Our team has been informed and will check this issue.

Comment: it works ,i changed  the function active($user) to active($id=null)